# how do range increments work?

Tags: weapons, ranged-attack, dnd-3e

I have seen range increments before in the player's handbook, but I'm not sure if they are how far the weapon can be used from, or if they are actual *increments*. can someone tell me?

Comment: Have you read the rules on them? Which part of them is unclear?

Comment: basically, are they the maximum of how far you can throw/shoot something?

Comment: So something like "How do you figure out the maximum range from the range increments in the weapon stats?"

Comment: I really have no Idea how they work, and I just want an explanation.

Comment: Your question is tagged [[tag:dnd-3e]], the third edition of D&D released in 2000. That edition was updated in 2004 to the “v.3.5 revised edition,” or [[tag:dnd-3.5e]]. It is still possible to play 3e, but the overwhelming majority of 3.x games are 3.5e, not 3e. If you are playing 3e, that’s fine and the question can stay as-is, but I wanted to point out that 3.5e might be more accurate. (I do not know if the answer to this question would be any different in one vs. the other.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From dandwiki.com:

> Any attack at less than this distance is not penalized for range.
> However, each full range increment causes a cumulative -2 penalty to
> the attack roll.
>
> Thrown weapons, such as throwing axes, have a maximum range of five range increments.
> Projectile weapons, such as bows, can shoot up to ten increments.

So it amounts to how far away a target can be attacked effectively.

A weapon with a range of 10ft can be thrown up to that distance with no attack penalty. However, should the target be 10-20 feet away, the attack would take a -2, 20-30 feet takes a -4, and so on.

Edit: Link https://dandwiki.com/wiki/3e_SRD:Weapon_Qualities#Range_Increment

Answer (score 3):

Player's Handbook, page 96 (under Weapon Qualities):

> Range  Increment:  Any  attack  at  less  than  this  distance  is
> not penalized  for  range,  so  an  arrow  from  a  shortbow  (range
> increment 60  feet)  can  strike  at  enemies  up  to  59  feet  away
> with  no  penalty. However,  each full range increment causes a
> cumulative –2 penalty to  the  attack  roll.  A  shortbow  archer
> firing  at  a  target  200  feet  away suffers  a –6  attack  penalty
> (because 200  feet  is  at  least  three  range increments  but  not
> four  increments).  Thrown  weapons,  such  as throwing  axes,  have
> a  maximum  range  of  five  range  increments. Projectile weapons,
> such as bows, can shoot up to ten increments.

It would seem that a shortbow could be used from up to 659 feet away. However, an attack from that distance would suffer from a -20 penalty.

Comment: This question is tagged [[tag:dnd-3e]], i.e. the third edition. The basic rules you quote are for the 5th edition, i.e. over a decade later.

Comment: My fault, for not reading the tags. Updated my answer to quote the correct rule book.

Comment: that's OK. so what that basically means is that to use a shortbow from 659 away with *overall* having a penalty, you would have to be about 17th level and a fighter/barbarian/paliden (not sure if I spelled that right, I don't have my D&D books with me right now). you would also by that time have a dexterity of about 16-17 for a plus three bonus